# Rails 3 - in each loop is printed HTML source instead data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, view, each

I am solving situation about printing data from array via each loop.

### in my controller

```
@dost_arr = ["aaab", "bbb", "ccc"]
```

### in view

```
                <% @dost_arr.each do |i| %>
                <%='<tr class="show_lines">'.html_safe%>
                    <%='<td colspan="2">x'+ (link_to i, request.request_uri+'&d=0')+'</td>'%>
                <%='</tr>'%>
            <%end%>
```

But this generate me something like this

```
<td colspan="2">x<a href="/hledani/index?utf8=%E2%9C%93&amp;n
```

as source code, so I see in browser  and not own data from array formatting into table...

Can anyone help me, please, what I am doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you put html code inside ruby code? Use something like this:

```
<% @dost_arr.each do |i| %>
    <tr class="show_lines">
       <td colspan="2">x + <%= (link_to i, request.request_uri+'&d=0')+'%> </td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

try using `raw` e.g.:

```
<%= raw '</tr>'%>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be looking at URL decoding. Check [this](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/5180) out.